# android listview of multiple types

Tags: android, listview

What I want to have is a listview populated with my custom `Folder` class at the top, and objects at the bottom. I was thinking it would look something like it does in an OS.

I've spent hours looking through tutorials online, but the best I could find was putting an image and some text in the same row.

To be clear, I'm looking for something like this:

Folder_1
Folder_2
Folder_3
Item_1
Item_2

all in the same list.

Could anyone here help me figure this out?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ - check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of list items in a `ListView` is controlled by the `getView()` method of the list's `Adapter`. Any kind of customization that you want to do on a per-item basis (which includes having totally different list items) can be done from the `getView()` method. If you share some of the code of what you have already tried, others can help you further.

Comment: @halfg33k: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my computer. Your answer indirectly solved the problem for me. I was able to refine my search and found what I was looking for here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296. Thanks so much for your help.